# Which is better to get current page link - get_permalink() or get_page_link()?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

For get_permalink() I saw that there's a complication when not using with loops, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

get_page_link() looks straight forward to me, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_link/

So which is better actually?

Comment: <?php echo get_the_permalink( get_the_ID() ); ?> This is better

Comment: Why not get_page_link() ? It seems simplest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_page_link()` is specific to the page post type, there is also `get_attachment_link()` and `get_post_permalink()` for attachments and posts respectively.

get_the_permalink() checks the post type and uses the appropriate function from above ones.

That's why i prefer `get_permalink()` or `get_the_permalink()`